# Autoit - searching for a URL in a web page and click on it

Tags: autoit

I'm trying to figure out how can I click a URL that matches a specific pattern.
For example:

```
#include <IE.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

local $pattern = "/123/"
Local $oIE = _IECreate("www.example.com",0,1,1,1)
Local $oLinks = _IELinkGetCollection($oIE)

For $oLink In $oLinks

    If StringInStr($oLink, $pattern)  Then
        _IEAction($oLink, "click")
        sleep(700)
        _IEQuit($oIE)
        ExitLoop
    EndIf
Next
```

Basically what I need to achieve is,
if a $oLink in $oLinks contains $pattern - click on it.
The above program, for some reason, does not work.

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: Not sure if you can use `StringInStr` on the object. Try using `StringInStr($oLink.href, $pattern)` instead.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can use `StringInStr` on the object.

Try using:

```
StringInStr($oLink.href, $pattern)
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

Do you get your links with this piece of code?

```
#include <Array.au3>
#include <Inet.au3>
local $pattern = "/123/"
$source = _INetGetSource('https://www.nytimes.com/')
$links = StringRegExp($source, 'href="(http.*?)"', 3)
_ArrayDisplay($links)
```

Then you just need to adapt your For Next loop and use StringInStr on every links[$i]